# R - Conditional operations on time variables and dates

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

Assumed, I have the dataframe below and want to do some operations on the last variable `HMS`. 
The aim is to create a new variable, lets say `TimeStampNew` and assign the next day if the observation is after `17:30:00` of the day. When the observation indicates no value (`'NA'`), then the `TimeStamp` of the same date should be used.

The problem is, to convert the `HMS`-variable from the class character in a format allowing for conditions. I already checked the chron-package or converting it to a object of type `POSIXct` as possible alternatives.

A similar question I already asked in this post: [R - Condition on character variable "weekday" and replace with special "date" in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512303/r-condition-on-character-variable-weekday-and-replace-with-special-date-in) .
I already tried to solve the issue with some operations of the `dplyr` package as suggested in the post mentioned above. However, I didn't receive the desired solution due to the tricky time format.

Has anybody an solution proposal to this question?!

Thanks in advance!

```
    TimeStamp      HMS
1  2010-02-22 19:55:00
2  2012-10-10 07:53:00
3  2012-10-24 07:55:00
4  2013-07-15 08:14:00
5  2013-07-24 08:23:00
6  2013-12-02 10:00:00
7  2012-02-23 07:56:00
8  2012-03-06 08:45:00
9  2013-09-15 19:54:00
10 2007-03-28 NA      
11 2007-08-09 NA      
12 2008-08-07 NA
```

Comment: Something like `TimeStamp + (!is.na(HMS) & HMS > "17:30:00")`? Your example is not easily reproducible so I'm not testing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `difftime` and an `ifelse` statement:

```
df1$TimeStamp <- as.Date(df1$TimeStamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df1$TimeStampNew <- ifelse(
  difftime(as.POSIXct(df1$HMS, format = "%H:%M:%S"), 
  as.POSIXct("17:30:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0,
  as.character(df1$TimeStamp + 1), 
  as.character(df1$TimeStamp))

df1$TimeStampNew[is.na(df1$HMS)] <- as.character(df1$TimeStamp[is.na(df1$HMS)])
```

The dataframe it produces:

```
> df1
    TimeStamp      HMS TimeStampNew
1  2010-02-22 19:55:00   2010-02-23
2  2012-10-10 07:53:00   2012-10-10
3  2012-10-24 07:55:00   2012-10-24
4  2013-07-15 08:14:00   2013-07-15
5  2013-07-24 08:23:00   2013-07-24
6  2013-12-02 10:00:00   2013-12-02
7  2012-02-23 07:56:00   2012-02-23
8  2012-03-06 08:45:00   2012-03-06
9  2013-09-15 19:54:00   2013-09-16
10 2007-03-28     <NA>   2007-03-28
11 2007-08-09     <NA>   2007-08-09
12 2008-08-07     <NA>   2008-08-07
```

Comment: Thanks! works well! The last line in syntax I changed to df1$TimeStampNew[is.na(df1$TimeStampNew)] <- as.character(df1$TimeStamp[is.na(df1$TimeStampNew)]) , in order to fill the NA's in TimeStampNew with values of the TimeStamp variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `DF` as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  In particular `Timestamp` and `HMS` are both assumed to be character columns.  `Timestamp` could alternately be a `"Date"` class column.

The code below replaces `NA` values in `HMS` column with `"00:00:00"` and adds 1 day to the `TimeStamp` (after converting it to `"Date"` class) if `HMS` is past 17:30.

```
transform(DF, Date = 
  as.Date(TimeStamp) + (replace(HMS, is.na(HMS), "00:00:00") > "17:30:00"))
```

giving this data frame where the new `Date` column is of class `"Date"`.

```
    TimeStamp      HMS       Date
1  2010-02-22 19:55:00 2010-02-23
2  2012-10-10 07:53:00 2012-10-10
3  2012-10-24 07:55:00 2012-10-24
4  2013-07-15 08:14:00 2013-07-15
5  2013-07-24 08:23:00 2013-07-24
6  2013-12-02 10:00:00 2013-12-02
7  2012-02-23 07:56:00 2012-02-23
8  2012-03-06 08:45:00 2012-03-06
9  2013-09-15 19:54:00 2013-09-16
10 2007-03-28     <NA> 2007-03-28
11 2007-08-09     <NA> 2007-08-09
12 2008-08-07     <NA> 2008-08-07
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
    TimeStamp      HMS
1  2010-02-22 19:55:00
2  2012-10-10 07:53:00
3  2012-10-24 07:55:00
4  2013-07-15 08:14:00
5  2013-07-24 08:23:00
6  2013-12-02 10:00:00
7  2012-02-23 07:56:00
8  2012-03-06 08:45:00
9  2013-09-15 19:54:00
10 2007-03-28 NA      
11 2007-08-09 NA      
12 2008-08-07 NA"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```