# R - Error in nested ifelse conditioned on character, time and date variables

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, nested, difftime

This questions is basically an extension to my following post [R - Conditional operations on time variables and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925200/r-conditional-operations-on-time-variables-and-dates/49926790#49926790)

The issue I have is due to an error occuring in the extension in form of a nested ifelse statement (e.g. see https://www.listendata.com/2017/03/if-else-in-r.html) accordingly the solution of @griffinevo. Assumed I have different closing times of the local stock exchanges (same time zone) I want to use nested ifelse statements to be able to distingush between the several closing times. The problem however, is the the following error:

```
     Error in ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Vienna"), difftime(as.POSIXct(HMS,  : 
  unused argument (ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Frankfurt"), difftime(as.POSIXct("22:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0, as.character(TimeStamp + 1), ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Frankfurt"), difftime(as.POSIXct("22:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0, as.character(TimeStamp + 1), as.character(TimeStamp))))
```

It seems that I have a mistake in the syntax, however I don't know what exactly is wrong.

Assumed, I have the following 3 Stock Exchanges: Vienna, Frankfurt and Hamburg and different closing times. I want to create a new variable `TimeStampNew` and increase the day by one if the varibale `HMS` is after the critical closing hours of the several stock exchange. Here, the first rows of the data frame df.

```
   TimeStamp      HMS StockExchange
     1: 2013-09-15 19:54:00        Vienna
     2: 2016-05-10 18:58:00        Vienna
     3: 2014-09-22 22:47:00        Hamburg
     4: 2012-01-30 18:03:00        Frankfurt
     5: 2013-05-24 08:00:00        Vienna
     6: 2013-06-07 11:45:00        Vienna
     7: 2016-11-30 12:39:00        Vienna
     8: 2007-03-28 NA              Vienna
     9: 2007-05-10 NA              Hamburg
    10: 2007-08-09 NA              Vienna
    11: 2007-11-08 NA              Frankfurt
    12: 2008-03-27 NA              Vienna
```

This is my syntax producing the error above:

```
   df$TimeStampNew <-
 with(df, 
      ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Vienna") , 
             difftime(as.POSIXct(HMS, format = "%H:%M:%S"), 
                      as.POSIXct("17:35:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0,
             as.character(TimeStamp + 1),
      ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Frankfurt") , 
             difftime(as.POSIXct("22:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0,
             as.character(TimeStamp + 1),
      ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Hamburg") , 
             difftime(as.POSIXct("20:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0,
             as.character(TimeStamp + 1),
             as.character(TimeStamp)))))

df1$TimeStampNew[is.na(df1$HMS)] <- as.character(df1$TimeStamp[is.na(df1$HMS)])
```

Has anybody an idea where the mistake is to be found respectively has an alternative possible solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're using for giving the two conditions in the ifelse is wrong. It should be something like,

```
ifelse(StockExchanges %in% c("Vienna") & 
         difftime(as.POSIXct(HMS, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
                  as.POSIXct("17:35:00", format = "%H:%M:%S")) > 0,
         as.character(TimeStamp + 1),
```

i.e. the two conditions should be separated by '&' and not a comma.
Just change this for all the ifelse conditions and it should run fine.